# Is this html5 structure correct?

Tags: css, html

I've been using an html5 doctype for a while now but haven't really been using many more tags than `header`, `nav` and `footer`. I would like to understand when to implement the `article` and `aside` tags and if in my example I am implementing them correctly.

The entire reason that I ask this question is because there seems to be a lot of controversy on how exactly they should be used and whether certain tags like the `aside` tag can be nested within the `article` tag. I'm just looking for clarity here.

Here is my example. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there anything about this layout that is incorrect?
2. Can I style `aside` these new tags or do I have to apply styles to the elements within the new html5 tags?

> ```
> <header>
>
> </header>
> <main>
>   <article id="article">
>     <div id="full">
>       <aside id="page-left">
>         <div>
>           <h1>title</h1>
>           <p>content</p>
>         </div>
>       </aside>
>       <aside id="page-right">
>         <div>
>           <h2>title</h2>
>           <p>content</p>
>         </div>
>       </aside>
>     </div>
>   </article>
> </main>
> <footer>
>
> </footer>
> ```

**EDIT:**

---

What I am after is simply a wrapper div that was changed to an `article` tag that will contain 2 inline elements. The left element will contain the actual article and the right side will contain testimonials.

What would the correct tags be in this case?

Comment: You seem to have an article with no content that isn't an aside, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. The article contains two aside tags. Each aside tag will have content. Should I be using 2 article tags?

Comment: Do you have two articles?

Comment: No, There is one article on the left with testimonials on the right. They are encompassed by the article tag. I've also posted up top in my post clarifying what I want to represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would normally put ads and other stuff that has nothing - or less - to do with the article, in `aside` tags. I can't tell you if you're using them properly since only you can decide whats necessary and what's not. But I guess you're using them fine. just make sure you don't put important stuff in them because google and other search engines won't show anything in `aside` tags in your websites description

EDIT: this is how - I think - your example should look:

```html
</header>
<main>
  <div id="full">
    <article id="page-left">
      <div>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <aside id="page-right">
      <div>
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's misleading though. Aside as in a physical location in relation to, or what?

Comment: Thanks Random, The right aside will have testimonials and the left aside will have an actual article.

Comment: @NaN don't do that! like I said, use the `aside` element for information that doesn't matter. the `article` element is for the actual article

Comment: OK, I'm going to edit my post showing what will be in each tag. Maybe this will help in determining what tag to use. Also, thank you for the info on google ignoring the aside tag content. That would have been bad for me if I would have used them

Comment: @NaN in HTML (almost)every tag has a purpose. The `article` tag is supposed to - contain the article! Currently you are using the `article` like a `div`. Btw: do you know what a `div` tag is for?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I use div, or division tags for layout

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. According to the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element): _"The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or sidebars, for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page."_ Ads are indeed a good use of the `<aside>` tag. The `<aside>` tag isn't meant for _"irrelevant unnecessary stuff"_ though. Sidebars and quotes are entirely necessary. Your statement is misleading...

Comment: @War10ck I know, but the spec is less important than what major search engines do. And I am quite sure the article is given priority, and if everything is in the article the first bits will be shown no matter how important the rest of the article is

Comment: Thanks War10ck for the comment. Random User just posted what he thinks should be used and I'm fine with it so long as the aside content gets crawled by google. They are testimonials on the right and should also be included in the index

Comment: @NaN everything will be indexed but the description - `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required. Take the 2-minute tour.` - will not contain anything less than top priority

Comment: @RandomUser True but the majority of bots index according to the spec so it's a good rule of thumb to follow the guidelines set forth. Not only will your markup be semantically correct, but it will be correctly crawled as well. The example you posted looks good. :) I was just clarifying to prevent future confusion.

Comment: @NaN The layout should work well for indexing services like Google. My comment was more on the semantics of the layout.

Comment: @War10ck I guess.. anyways, no problem :)

Comment: OK, then it's settled, I will use Random's example. Thanks to both of you for all your help!

Comment: Thank you Random for the code example as well as the info. Can I style the aside tags as I would a div tag?

Comment: @NaN yeah, you can style aside and article tags just like div tags

Answer (score 1):

From W3C:

--

> The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content. Each article should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the article element.
>   A general rule is that the article element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.

--

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.
>   The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or sidebars, for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

--

So I would not put the article content inside an `aside` tag.

[more here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html)

Comment: Thank you Khan. If you were me, how would you lay this out? The main meat of the page will be in the left and right aside tags. The right aside will have testimonials and the left aside will have an actual article. Can you show me how you might lay this out?